# How to Avoid ANR response in Android when there is a Time delay in Server?

Tags: java, android, web-services, android-anr-dialog

I am new to Android, but i know somewhat in Java, and Java EE
While communicating with the Server(webservice) , it works fine with the response i am getting from it.
But if there is any time delay more than 5 seconds, it is going to `ANR`. Now my question is how to check with my java functionality , to know whether the server is responding or not responding . Any ideas in this??

Even some Related examples will help me.

**Code Snippet**

```
Handler handler = new Handler(); 
handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() { 
    public void run() { 
             // Problem is if Server is not Working , it delays and the UI wents to ANR 
              if(  sendToWebservice(String_to_send)=="fromWebservice") {
                Toast.makeText(context, "Connected", 500).show();

              }
             else {
                Toast.makeText(context, "Not Connected,Try again ", 500).show();
                finish();
            }
     } 
    }, 5000);
```

Additional Info:
I am using `jax.ws` to create `webservice` & `ksoap api` in Android.
Thanks in Advance.

**Edit**

```
if(  sendToWebservice(String_to_send).equalIgnorecase("fromWebservice") instead of ==
```

I missed to put this while framing it into syntax here..!!

Comment: Don't do it on UI thread... And no, Handler is not new Thread...

Comment: @Selvin: ok !!  i got ur point .. ll refer documentation too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of All,
This condition should be,

```
if(sendToWebservice(String_to_send).equals("fromWebservice"))
```

Now for **ANR**,

You can put **response timeout in your HTTP request** so, if there is time delay then you get timeout response from server, Also if possible display some **progress dialog** when any webservice call has made in UI thread and your web service call in other worker thread.